# The function password_verify() returns false when it should return true

Tags: php, authentication

I'm creating a project for a contest at my school.I've done the register part correctly.When it comes to the login part,I can't get it right.I tried looking the problem up on many other sites but can't find it.The functions returns false even when I type the password into the function.

I tried hashing ,with password_BCRYPT,the password that I get from $_POST['password'] and then comparing to the password in the database with hash_equals() but it didn't work

This is the login.php
EDIT: I forgot to add the register.php and the file_db.php.Sorry!

```
<?php
require "file_db.php";
$email= $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
echo $_POST['email'];
$result= $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $SESSION['message']="Nu exista niciun utilizator cu acel email";
    header("location:error.php");
} else {
    $user=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $hash=substr($user['password'],0,60);
    if(password_verify($_POST['password'],$hash)) {
        $_SESSION['email']=$user['email'];
        $_SESSION['firstname']=$user['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname']=$user['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['active']=$user['active'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
        echo $_SESSION['loggedin'];
        echo 1;
    } else{
        $_SESSION['message']="Ai introdus o parola gresita!";
    }
}
?>
```

```````
<?php
require "file_db.php";

$firstname = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password =$mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$hash = $mysqli->escape_string(md5(rand(0,1000) ) );

$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['firstname']=$_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname']=$_POST['lastname'];

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$email' ") or die($mysqli->error());

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['message']='Exista un utilizator cu acest email deja!';
    header("location:error.php");
}
else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,password,hash)".
        "VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$hash')";
    if( $mysqli->query($sql) )
    {
        $_SESSION['active']=0;
        $_SESSION['message']="Link  de confirmare a fost trimis la $email, te rugam sa iti verifici contul accesand link-ul trimis in email!";

        $to = $email;
        $subject='Account Verification';
        $messageb='
        Salut'.$firstname.',
        Multumim pentru ca te-ai inscris!
        Apasa pe acest link pentru a-ti activa contul:
        https://localhost/aWEBDEVFII/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash'.$hash;
        mail($to, $subject, $messageb);

        header("location:success.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message']='Inregistrarea a intampinat o eroare!';
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}
?>
``````




<?php
session_start();
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db='filesdb';
$mysqli= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
```````

Comment: `substr($user['password'],0,60);` eh?

Comment: What is `var_dump($user['password']);`?

Comment: mmh, you modify the hash and wonder why the verification fails? Why the are you doing this? additional side note: hashing and encrypting are different thing.

Comment: @Qirel var_dump($user['password']); is string(60) "$2y$10$TVDLLUcuKEsBDaXPaU7haOWvsTpLbg6aELmCao1PKewxpxadysieu"

Answer (score 0):

First why are you applying `substr()` function to hashed password

The `substr()` function is used to cut a part of a string from a string, starting at a specified position etc.

If you want to check the length of password entered, you should use `strlen()`
and then return a message to user if password length execeeds 60

```
if (strlen($password)<60) {
  echo "less than 60";
}
else
if (strlen($password)>40) {
  echo "more than 60";
}
else {
  echo "exactly 60";
}
```

To be able to use `password_verify()` you should be able to first hashed the users password during signup
via `password_hash()` function. Eg.

```
 $password ='nancymore12344444';
 $options = array("cost"=>4);
 $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
```

**Again they will be an issue in your login script because I did not see were you initialize session via session_start()**

Try code below while ensuring that database credentials and all table column are put in place. you will be fine

so your signup php will look something like

```
<?php
//require "file_db.php"; 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['first_name']);
        $surName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['surname']);
        $email  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

        $options = array("cost"=>4);
        $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);

        $sql = "insert into users (first_name, last_name,email, password) value('".$firstName."', '".$surName."', '".$email."','".$hashPassword."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "Registration successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

your login

```
<?php 
//require "file_db.php";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","demo");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

    $sql = "select * from users where email = '".$email."'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    if($numRows  == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
        if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
            echo "Password verified and ok";

// initialize session if things where ok.


session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

$_SESSION['surname'] = $row['surname'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

// take me to welcome.php page
header('Location: welcome.php');

        }
        else{
            echo "Wrong Password details";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "User does not exist";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I use a more complex register system.I generate a random hash in order to identify the user when sending a confirmation mail.I use a variable that tells  me if the user has activated his account or not.I don't think I can add this to the register.php that you posted.

Comment: Remember that the issue you are having is that you cannot login due to your code malfunctioning. I just added a register button to show you how you will generate users password prior to login. So I was wondering where the issue sending email confirmation   comes from. whatever you are doing with your code is up to you. Am just here to help. so if you like you can re-invent the wheel,  roll out your own encryption method and hash it as never done before. is up to you.  your comment is out of the scope of the post.